# Simple .NET method of a parallel work queue with controllable concurrency

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, threadpool

This sounds like an overly trivial question, and I think I am overcomplicating it because I haven't been able to find the answer for months. There are easy ways of doing this in Golang, Scala/Akka, etc but I can't seem to find anything in .NET.

What I need is an ability to have a list of Tasks that are all independent of each other, and the ability to execute them concurrently on a specified (and easily changeable) number of threads.

Basically something like:

```
int numberOfParallelThreads = 3;                // changeable
Queue<Task> pendingTasks = GetPendingTasks();   // returns 80 items

await SomeBuiltInDotNetParallelExecutableManager.RunAllTasksWithSpecifiedConcurrency(pendingTasks, numberOfParallelThreads);
```

And that `SomeBuiltInDotNetParallelExecutableManager` would execute 80 tasks three at a time; i.e. when one finishes it draws the next one from the queue, until the queue is exhausted.

There is `Task.WhenAll` and `Task.WaitAll`, but you can't specify the max number of parallel threads in them.

Is there a built in, simple way to do this?

Comment: How about a thread pool?
https://owlcation.com/stem/C-ThreadPool-and-its-Task-Queue-Example

Comment: By "controllable concurrency" do you mean that you want to specify the level of concurrency *before* starting the parallel work, or that you want to be able to change the level of concurrency *while* the parallel work is running? In the first case, is the [`Parallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel) class and the [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism) option close to what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync?view=net-6.0) (or depending on actual workload it's sync counterpart - [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=net-6.0), but it will not handle functions returning `Task` correctly):

```cs
IEnumerable<int> x = ...;

await Parallel.ForEachAsync(x, new ParallelOptions
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3
}, async (i, token) => await Task.Delay(i * 1000, token));
```

Also it is highly recommended that methods in C# return so called "hot", i.e. started tasks, so "idiomatically" `Queue<Task>` should be a collection of already started tasks, so you will have no control over number of them executing in parallel because it will be controlled by `ThreadPool`/`TaskScheduler`.

And there is port of Akka to .NET - [Akka.NET](https://getakka.net/) if you want to go down that route.

Comment: Brilliant, that's exactly what I needed. Side question: so it would be more conventional to return a list of `Action`s instead of `Task`s?

Comment: @Ruslan since, as I wrote, `Task`'s should (by convention) be started, to achieve your goal you should have collection of `Action`'s  of `Func<Task>`'s

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's Reactive Framework makes this easy too:

```
IEnumerable<int> values = ...;

IDisposable subscription =
    values
        .ToObservable()
        .Select(v => Observable.Defer(() => Observable.Start(() => { /* do work on each value */ })))
        .Merge(3)
        .Subscribe();
```